# ViewPagerIndicator - Set the TabPageIndicator to the center

Tags: java, android, horizontalscrollview, android-scrollview, viewpagerindicator

I make an timetable application for [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) and I'm using [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) as fragment. But now I've a problem, I want to get the TabPageIndicator to the center. Like this:
[image: Example]

And I would to like to set the individual tab width and height. And set that tab to a drawable that support selected/pressed states.

I've not found it yet to solve these problems. I've try something with `onPageSelected` and `ContextThemeWrapper` but that doesn't work. (Maybe I'm not using it correctly).

Is this all possible to make or should I look to something else than ViewPagerIndicator? (An other option without ViewPagerIndicator is also welcome).

<sup>The app on the image is Untis Mobile and can be found on the PlayStore. 
I've already ask the creators how they do it but they said the app isn't open source. (But I have found in the source that they do it with [TwoDScrollView](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/), but I'm not sure)</sup>

**Edit:**

The styling is fixed with `vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle`. (With help of XDA Developers!)

When I add 20 items it stays on the middle but only from item 4 to item 17, item 1, 2, 3, 18, 19, 20 are not in the middle. See:

[image: Wrong]

Can I add a 3 empty items (or empty space) to ensure that the first and last items are in the middle? Something like this (from the Untis Mobile app):

[image: Good]

<sup>(I've already tried `android:paddingLeft` in `vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle` but that doesn't work)</sup>

I know that `viewPager.setCurrentItem(total/2)` will set the TabPageIndicator in the middle but then it stays on the middle and I'm not able to select a other day (I call it in `onPageScrolled`). So I want as you scroll the selected one needs to be in the middle. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

The widget you are looking for is similar to the android horizontal wheel. There is an implementation at [android-spinnerwheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel) which can be what you need.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Then you don't need an viewpagerindicator. Use a horizontal scroll view as Amulya Khare suggested in your activity and replace fragments when scrolling occurs.

Your activity layout could be like :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <SomeWheelView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />
        <SomeStaticIndicatorView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />
        <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Set a listener to wheelview and when change occurs you can put your fragments in framelayout in your activity.

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this :

```
TabPagerIndicator tbi;
   ViewPager pager;
```

in `onCreate()` do like this

```
tbi=(TabPagerIndicator)findViewById(R.id.something);
   tbi.setViewPager(pager);
```

I hope this will work out for you. :D