# android-spinnerwheel - Individual tab drawable

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-drawable, android-library

I would to like to set the individual tab width and height in WheelHorizontalView (which is included in the library [`android-spinnerwheel`](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel)). And set that tab to a drawable that supports  selected/pressed states.

This can be done in `ViewPagerIndicator` (with `vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle`), but I can't do that using this library. (This is how I've done it with `vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle`: http://pastebin.com/wB4vGMyJ)

What I've tried is to change the `selectionDivider` to this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_daychooser_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_daychooser_item_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_daychooser_item_default" />
</selector>
```

But that's not working. I've looked into `wheel__attrs.xml` but I could not find another attribute that has as format an drawable (reference).

This is how it's now:

[image: before]

And this is how I want it:

[image: after]

If you're wondering why I've switched from `ViewPagerIndicator` to [`android-spinnerwheel`](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel) see here: [ViewPagerIndicator - Set the TabPageIndicator to the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764866/viewpagerindicator-set-the-tabpageindicator-to-the-center)

I've also asked this question on the [`android-spinnerwheel`](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel) GitHub page, but after 4 months without any reply I've decided to also ask it here.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @sdeff Not yet, but the owner of [android-spinnerwheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel/) says that it shouldn't be too tricky to implement. Sadly he's out of free time these days. Implementing by myself is some kind of problem because I'm not that experienced with Java or Android development.

Comment: In the current code, just find out how that guy has made the font color bit darker, there you have to apply the code which will change the background.

Answer (score 0):

I changed text color in my WheelAdapter simply by-

```
        @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getItem(index, cachedView, parent);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setTextColor(index==minute?Color.WHITE:Color.BLACK);
        return view;
    }
```